# how to pretty_print xincluded file?

Tags: python, xml, io

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("part_000001.xml")
tree.xinclude()
string = etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)

print(string)
```

I'm trying to pretty_print an XML file, my pretty_print option is turned on in the console (%%pprint to turn it on and off), but the terminal still doesn't insert an actual newline and instead "\n" is included in the string.

How to change it so that the newline is actually inserted?

Answer (score 0):

U can try `BeautifulSoup` and using prettify() u can format your code as so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#you will FIRST need to read the xml file to pass into BS as shown below

content = []
with open("part_000001.xml", "r") as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    content = "".join(content)
    bs_content = bs(content, "lxml")

print(bs_content.prettify())
```

You can read more on this [here](https://linuxhint.com/parse_xml_python_beautifulsoup/).

Answer (score 0):

the bytes must first be turned into a string:

```
string = etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8") #decode will convert bytes into string
```